# Do i need server for autorenuable in app purchase

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

Sorry for posting this question again.

But I want to know "Do i need server for auto renewable in app purchase"

Can I go without help of server ?

I have checked many threads on google but did not find any satisfied answer.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to use your own server for this. But the reason it's recommended is that, if you want to verify receipts with iTunes from the app (instead of your server) you'd have to include your secret in the app.

Comment: you mean for Autorenewable app ?